# Grouping symmetric points in 2D domain

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list of points

```
L = {
    {-0.980187,-1.07694}, {-0.980187,1.07694},
    {-0.788396,-1.81236},{-0.788396,1.81236},
    {-0.437793,-1.07694},{-0.437793,1.07694},
    {-0.157935,-1.81236},{-0.157935,1.81236},
    {0.157935,-1.81236},{0.157935,1.81236},
    {0.437793,-1.07694},{0.437793,1.07694},
    {0.788396,-1.81236},{0.788396,1.81236},
    {0.980187,-1.07694},{0.980187,1.07694}
}
```

Which are distributed in four symmetric sets each having the points $(x,y), (-x,y),(x,-y),(-x,-y)$

(see image below).
[image]

**I'd like to group the points based in their symmetry in a new list `L1`
in the following way**

$L1 = \{l1,l2,l3,l4\},$
where $l_i = \{\{x_i, y_i\},\{-x_i, y_i\},\{x_i, -y_i\},\{-x_i, -y_i\}\}, i=1,2,3,4$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html)`[data,`[`Abs`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html)`]`

```
ClearAll[L, l];

L = GatherBy[data, Abs];

l[n_] := L[[n]]

ListPlot[ L ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really amazing and works for any list what ever the length is.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
Map[Extract[L, #] &, Reverse@Partition[List /@ OrderingBy[L, Abs], {4}]] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
l1 = Select[L, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &]
l2 = Select[L, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &]
l3 = Select[L, #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &]
l4 = Select[L, #[[1]] < 0 && #[[2]] < 0 &]
```

Visualization

```
ListPlot[{l1, l2, l3, l4}, PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}]
```

> [image: lp]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. GatherBy seems to be easier.

Comment: I interpreted this question similarly.